# If the row contains specific text highlight row by row where two columns are the same

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, countif

I currently use conditional formatting on columns M and N on a spreadsheet to fill duplicate number values using the formula:

`=COUNTIF($M1:$N1,M1)>1`

I was asked by my boss if I could only conditionally format columns M and N if a specific text name in column G appears on that same row. Is there a way to add this to my formula or would this need something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe add an AND to your formula:

```
=AND($G1="name",COUNTIF($M1:$N1,M1)>1)
```

Comment: pnuts you are my hero yet again. This was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would want to put a vlookup in your conditional formatting formula.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want countif to be able to handle two conditions. You could also use

`=countifs(data_range1,condition1,data_range2,condition2)`

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53c4dc8e-0e5b-4e32-93df-9ca5e7da89ed

Example:

> Assume you have column A with values from 1-10. Column B has values of 1 and 2 alternating as you go down the column. If you use
>
> `=countif(A1:A10,">2")`
>
> the value equates to 8. If you use
>
> `=countifs(A1:A10,">2",B1:B10,">1")`
>
> the values equates to 4. The second equations skipped 4 numbers because both conditions are not met.

To reference a cell for determining the condition you can use

`=countifs(data_range1,">"&G1,data_range2,condition2)`